# R: propensity match within range of continuous variable?

Tags: r, propensity-scores

I'm working on a retrospective analysis on some oncology data using R. I'm trying to do a lot of the analysis myself.

My colleagues have used SPSS in the past and have asked me to specify limits for matching in continuous variables. For example, specifying match according to age +/- 5 years, tumor size +/- 5 mm, etc.

Is it possible to do this using the MatchIt or a comparable package?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want variable-specific calipers.

In the `Matching` package (not `MatchIt`), you can specify a vector of values to the `caliper` argument in `Match()` or `GenMatch()`. The values are expected to be in standardized units, so you'll have to compute how many standardized units each of your defined calipers are.

In the `designmatch` package, you can specify the maximum distance between any pair of units on any given covariates using the `near` argument in `bmatch()`. I recommend this option and recommend this package for matching in general.

In `MatchIt`, you can specify a vector of values to the `caliper` argument, which is passed directly to `Matching::GenMatch()` if you are doing genetic matching (i.e., `method = "genetic"`), but not otherwise. Because it's less clear how `MatchIt` processes the covariates that are passed to `GenMatch()`, use this method with caution.

---

**Update**:

As of version 4.0.0, you can specify variable-specific calipers using `MatchIt`. For example, to restrict eligible matches on `age` and `size`, you could run

```
matchit(treat ~ X1 + X2 + age + size, data = data,
        caliper = c(age = 5, size = 5), std.caliper = FALSE)
```

This would restrict matches so that pairs are within 5 years of age of each other and within 5 mm of size of each other.